# What are the odds of drawing a pocket pair in poker?

Tags: combinatorics, poker

In poker, you make a pocket pair when the ranks of your first two cards match. This does not include making a pair on the flop or in a full 7-card hand.

There are six ways to draw a pocket pair of a given rank, but how many ways are there to draw *any* pocket pair, and what are the odds of doing so?

##### Footnotes

1. Posting as an answer for my own reference, and because the [Poker StackExchange question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/pocket-pair-starting-hands-vs-probability-of-opponent-having-a-pocket-pair) did not support LaTeX.
2. **Not a duplicate**: While there are other questions on MSE related to flopping a pair or making one in a full 7-card hand, this question is limited to just *pocket pairs* (your private 2-card hand).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Nij Link one then. There's not a canonical answer to this question on this StackExchange, I checked.

Comment: [Take your pick](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Poker+pair+probability). "But the others aren't closed as duplicate of one specific other!" is not an argument that supports leaving yet another post lying around which should not have been created in the first place.

Comment: At a minimum, you should edit your post to explain what a "pocket pair" is.  While this is a term in  standard use among card players, I don't think it is universally understand by mathematicians. Maybe not even by me... Personally, I thought it was just a pair preflop...in which case the answer is obviously $\frac 3{51}$, right?  The first card can be anything and then there are $3$ candidates for the second.

Comment: That ends up being logically the same answer, but they are substantively different questions. Yes, it is just a pair preflop, I updated to clarify. Also it is maybe not so obvious to everyone, especially in terms of combinations like I wanted to know.

Comment: They are literally the same questions.  At least, I see no difference at all between them.  Again, I suggest editing your post to include the definition of a "pocket pair".  I thought it just meant you were dealt a pair as your first two "hole" cards.  But then, of course, you are just asking for the probability that a random draw of two cards from an ordinary $52$ card decks is a pair, as in the duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

Any pocket pair will consist of one rank and two suits. Thus, there are $\dbinom 4 2 = 6$ ways to choose 2 suits from the 4 suits of a given rank, and $\dbinom {4}{2}\dbinom{13}{1} = 78$ ways to choose a pocket pair from all 13 ranks.

Because there are $\dbinom{52}{2} = 1326$ ways to choose any 2-card hand from a 52-card deck, the probability of drawing a pocket pair is:

$$
\frac{\dbinom {4}{2}\dbinom{13}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{2}} = \frac{78}{1326} = \frac{3}{51} = 5.8823\% \text{ (16:1 odds)}
$$

This simplifies to $\frac{3}{51}$ because given any first card from the deck, 3 cards in the remaining deck of 51 complete the pocket pair.

---

1. See the [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) Wikipedia article for background on notation.

Comment: Why do you post questions you are answering yourself in the same instant ? MSE isn't a Q&A repository for ones own reference.

Comment: If Stack Exchange did not want users to both ask and answer simultaneously, it would not have created the function to do exactly that. @KurtG. If you have a problem in using the site as a reference, you should explain why nobody else would want such a reference, or just remove the irrelevant meta commentary and leave the rest.

Comment: @KurtG. I used the Q&A feature on purpose. I don't care if you don't like it.

Comment: You want the probability that two random cards from a deck are a matching pair. Whatever the first card is, there remain $51$ cards, equally likely to be the second card, of which $3$ match the first, so the desired value is $3/51 = 1/17$.

Comment: Note that a probability of $\frac 1{17}$ *does not* correspond to odds of $17:1$.  The odds, instead, are $16:1$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I updated.

Comment: @Ned Yes, I updated, but also wanted to understand in terms of combinations.